# Powershell script using a function

Tags: function, powershell, delete-file

I need to create a script to delete folders older than x number of days that are supplied in a separate text file. the format of the txt file is given in the comments section.
I need to figure out why the function is not loading; I get the following error:

clean : The term 'clean' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
path is correct and try again

Please help. Here is my script:

```
<#######################################################################
Use:  Enter UNC path of the folder and files that need to be deleted on 
        the path specified by $info variable
        Enter the entries in the txt file in the following format:
        "UNCPATH;DAYSTOKEEP;FILEEXTENSION"  
########################################################################>
CD C:\FileCleanup

@(
$info = get-content Directories.txt

foreach ($i in $info)
{
   $item = $i.split(";")
   if (Test-Path -Path ($item[0]) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
   {
       #write-host "UNC:       " $item[0]
       #write-host "Days:      " $item[1]
       #write-host "Extension: " $item[2]
       clean $item[0] $item[1] $item[2]
       Write-Output ("cleaned: `""+$i)
   }
   else #Log the paths that are missing
   {Write-Output ("MISSING PATH `""+$i)}
}

)|Out-file -FilePath CleanedUpFiles.txt

function clean
{
param ([string]$Dir, [int]$Days, [string]$Extension)

$cutoff = (get-date).AddDays(-$Days)

    # Delete any files older than $limit

Get-ChildItem $Dir -Filter *.$Extension -Recurse| 
        ?{$_.LastWriteTime -lt $cutoff -and !$_.PSIsContainer}| remove-item

#Logging
    write-output "$Dir *.$Extension, Keeping $Days days worth of files"

    # Delete any empty directories left behind after deleting the old files.
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir -Recurse -Force | 
        Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and (
            Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force |
        Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null } |
        Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your clean function before you use it, i.e. just below the comments explaining how the script works

Comment: Yep, I have found that the safest way for me to write scripts is to have script parameters up top, help/examples next (if I bother), then functions, and the actual script is the last thing. May not be best practice, I don't know, but I found it works well for me.